# Deleted Bookmarks (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have tried following the steps for restoring bookmarks but I can't seem to get them working. I have successfully recovered my bookmarks with the Recuva recovery tool.  I have them on my desktop: Bookmark and Bookmark.bak

But when I close Chrome, put the two files in the "Default" Chrome folder, delete the `Bookmark` file, and rename `Bookmark.bak` into `Bookmark`, it doesn't work.  I still don't have any bookmarks.

Unfortunately I don't have a system recovery point, so that isn't an option.

Comment: Recovering a file, and recovering the whole file and all the sectors that belongs to it, are 2 different things. while you may have restored the file, the file may not be complete or it may be corrupted.  Create in the program a valid bookmarks file item by adding in bookmarks, then view a good one with a HexEditor , then view your recovered file item with the same editor.  See if your recovered item, has the proper heading stuff at the top, and whatever ending it may use at the bottom.  Incomplete you may be able to put a standard ending on by editing the ending with the editor. Then try.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are syncing your browser data, please try these steps:

1. Sign in to your [Google Dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync)
2. See if you **have a bookmarks**, if yes then go to your **Chrome menu** under **Settings** there is a **Sign in** section
3. Select **Disconnect your google account**
4. At the end of the page "Setting" chose **Show advanced settings**
5. At the end chose **Reset Settings button**
6. Uninstall google chrome, then install the latest version
7. After the first start **Sign in with your google account to re-sync** your data and bookmarks again from google server "*can take few minutes depends on your internet connection to load all your data*".

Hope this could help you.